# How can I get user selection on image maps to js variable

Tags: javascript, html, image, mapping, frontend

I mapped an image and I want to take ids of those maps as an answer to my js variable.

```
<img src="img/beyin3.png" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area onclick="cevap = 'frontal'" id="frontal" alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="228,485,282,375,323,305,353,269,400,166,402,120,412,84,341,114,265,142,198,187,130,243,90,331,94,406,107,461" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="388,572,464,533,522,509,615,477,670,452,701,409,736,372,736,348,625,332,555,333,498,351,444,374,385,402,337,451,301,489,312,528" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="456,274,562,273,656,283,741,286,804,249,790,210,728,174,695,145,655,118,579,104,547,99" />
    <area alt="" title="" href="#" shape="poly" coords="757,460,837,456,876,443,894,411,904,380,904,347,889,330,871,303,855,280,846,278,830,278,799,309" />
</map>
<p style="text-align:bottom; margin-top:30%;">
    <h1><p id="soru"></p></h1></center>
```

Javascript code

```
function myFunction() {
    var ran = Math.floor((Math.random() * soruCevap.length));
    document.getElementById("soru").innerHTML = soruCevap[ran][0];
    var cevap;

    if(cevap.equals("frontal")){
        document.getElementById("soru").innerHTML = cevap;
    } else if(cevap.equals("temporal")){

    } else if(cevap.equals("paryetal")){

    } else if(cevap.equals("oksipital")){

    }
}
```

Comment: give id to other areas.

Comment: @marmeladze but this doesnt work either

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not have an `equals` method unless you've monkeypatched some data types. Possibly you've confused [java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and javascript.

What you should do is, to change

```
if(cevap.equals("frontal"))
```

to,

```
if(cevap === "frontal")
```